# Pandas: use to_csv() with quotation marks and a comma as a seperator

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, export-to-csv

I'm new to pandas, and I'm having trouble exporting to the correct CSV format for another system.

Source file looks like this with fields seperated by a quotation marks and a comma.

```
"User ID","Description","User Name"
"user1","John","john01"
"user2","Mike","mike33"
"user3","Barry","barry66"
```

I want to export in the same format but I am unable to .

I tried

```
csvfiledf.to_csv(outputcsv, index=False,  sep='\",\"')
```

but get

```
TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The delimiter in your output file is still `,`. What you need to modify is the `quoting` argument:

```
import csv
csvfiledf.to_csv(outputcsv, index=False, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

The `delimiter` argument is optional, since `,` is implied.

Comment: I got this working thanks, but the quoting parameter was an integer and not a boolean - e.g. `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL`